# Haskell - indexing a list

Tags: list, haskell, types, tuples, type-mismatch

I have a list of 3 tuples items, I would like to index the list based on the first item, I have already written a code that sounds logically sane to me yet am getting a type error, here's what I wrote

```
addIndex [] indexed = indexed
addIndex ((a1,b1,c1):xs) [] 
                    = addIndex xs [(a1,b1,c1,0)]
addIndex ((a1,b1,c1):xs) indexedWIP 
                    = addIndexH ((a1,b1,c1):xs) indexedWIP (last indexedWIP)
addIndexH ((a1,b1,c1):xs) indexedWIP (ax,bx,cx,ix)
                    = if (a1 /= ax) 
                        then (addIndex xs (indexedWIP ++ (a1,b1,c1,(ix+1)))) 
                        else (addIndex xs (indexedWIP ++ (a1,b1,c1,(ix))))
```

I'm getting the following type error

```
ERROR file:.\lmaogetrektson.hs:109 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : indexedWIP ++ (a1,b1,c1,ix + 1)
*** Term           : (a1,b1,c1,ix + 1)
*** Type           : (b,c,d,e)
*** Does not match : [a]
```

Comment: That's not a list with three elements, but a 3-tuple.

Comment: jeez dude you always seem to come bash at me for really simple terminologies or ask me to provide extra when you never give any input to my questions. edited it to tuples ...

Comment: not at all, but there is a fundamental difference between tuples and lists: you can *not* append lists with `++`, tuples always have fixed number of items (known at compile time), the elements can have different elements, etc. So your `indexedWIP ++ (...)` will not work out, since you can not append tuples.

Comment: You may want to indent that a bit :P

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You meant "you can not append _tuples_ with `++`". @Omar lists and tuples really behave differently, Willem was not trying to bash at you, but to point out the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me examine the types of your `addIndex` at each row:

```
addIndex :: [a] -> b -> b
addIndex [] indexed = indexed

-- Combined with the above, leads to:
addIndex :: (Num n) => [(a,b,c)] -> [(a,b,c,n)] -> [(a,b,c,n)]
addIndex ((a1,b1,c1):xs) [] = addIndex xs [(a1,b1,c1,0)]

-- This call demands addIndexH satisfies:
addIndexH :: (Num n) => [(a,b,c)] -> [(a,b,c,n)] -> (a,b,c,n) -> [(a,b,c,n)]
-- It's also costly, as last needs to traverse the list
addIndex ((a1,b1,c1):xs) indexedWIP = 
    addIndexH ((a1,b1,c1):xs) indexedWIP (last indexedWIP)

-- /= check matches types of a1 and ax, requiring them to be Eq
addIndexH ((a1,b1,c1):xs) indexedWIP (ax,bx,cx,ix) = 
    if (a1 /= ax) then (addIndex xs (indexedWIP ++ (a1,b1,c1,(ix+1)))) 
    else (addIndex xs (indexedWIP ++ (a1,b1,c1,(ix))))
```

The distinction of list and tuple is actually the problem you hit here.

```
Prelude> :t (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Both operands to `++` must be same-type lists. So we need something like:

```
addIndexH ((a1,b1,c1):xs) indexedWIP (ax,bx,cx,ix) = 
    if (a1 /= ax) then (addIndex xs (indexedWIP ++ [(a1,b1,c1,(ix+1))])) 
    else (addIndex xs (indexedWIP ++ [(a1,b1,c1,(ix))]))
```

The end result should be a function that takes a list of 3-tuples and another list of enumerated 4-tuples, but in a rather circuitous manner. Consider how it expands:

```
addIndex [(a,b,c), (x,y,z)] []
addIndex [(x,y,z)] [(a,b,c,0)]
addIndexH [(x,y,z)] [(a,b,c,0)] (a,b,c,0)
addIndex [] ([(a,b,c,0)] ++ [(x,y,z,(0+1))])
([(a,b,c,0)] ++ [(x,y,z,(0+1))])
```

That's a fairly complex procedure, and it grows worse the longer the lists are (we haven't even looked at duplicate a fields yet).

When you do encounter a duplicate a field, you still append it, only keeping the new index value. This means, since we only checked against the last item, that we have two items of matching `a` and index right next to each other. The function could be rewritten in several ways, in particular without rebuilding lists of every intermediate length and traversing the growing one for each element.

Answer (score 2):

I think you make it more complex than necessary. If I understand it correctly, you take as input a list of 3-tuples `(a, b, c)`, and you want to return a list of 4-tuples `(a, b, c, i)`, where `i` specifies the thus far number of different `a`-values we observed.

We thus perform some sort of mapping but with an accumulator. Although we can use higher-order constructs here, let us here aim to use recursion and add an accumulator. We can first define a helper function with signature:

```
addIndex' :: (Num n, Eq a) => a -> n -> [(a, b, c)] -> [(a, b, c, n)]
```

where the first parameter is thus the `a`-value of the *previous* element (we here assume that we processed already an element). The second parameter is the number of elements we thus far observed, the third elements is the list of elements we still have to process, and the result is the list of 4-tuples.

In case the list is exhausted, then we can return the empty list, regardless of the other variables:

```
addIndex' _ _ [] = []
```

in the other case, we should compare the previous key `ap` with the current key `a`, and in case the two are equal, we return the tuple with the index `i` as last element, we then recurse with the *same* index; otherwise we increment the index (to `i1 = i + 1`). We each time recurse on the tail of the list:

```
addIndex' ap i ((a, b, c): xs) | a == ap = (a, b, c, i) : addIndex' a i xs
                               | otherwise = (a, b, c, i1) : addIndex' a i1 xs
    where i1 = i + 1
```

So we obtain the function:

```
addIndex' :: (Num n, Eq a) => a -> n -> [(a, b, c)] -> [(a, b, c, n)]
addIndex' _ _ [] = []
addIndex' ap i ((a, b, c): xs) | a == ap = (a, b, c, i) : addIndex' a i xs
                               | otherwise = (a, b, c, i1) : addIndex' a i1 xs
    where i1 = i + 1
```

But now we still have to process the first element. We know that if the list is empty, we return the empty list:

```
addIndex [] = []
```

otherwise we return as first tuple the first one in the given list with index `0`, and then make a call to `addIndex'` with the remaining tuples and the first key as accumulator:

```
addIndex ((a, b, c): xs) = (a, b, c, 0) : addIndex' a 0 xs
```

so we obtain as full solution:

```
addIndex :: (Num n, Eq a) => [(a, b, c)] -> [(a, b, c, n)]
addIndex [] = []
addIndex ((a, b, c): xs) = (a, b, c, 0) : addIndex' a 0 xs

addIndex' :: (Num n, Eq a) => a -> n -> [(a, b, c)] -> [(a, b, c, n)]
addIndex' _ _ [] = []
addIndex' ap i ((a, b, c): xs) | a == ap = (a, b, c, i) : addIndex' a i xs
                               | otherwise = (a, b, c, i1) : addIndex' a i1 xs
    where i1 = i + 1
```

Then we generate for example:

```
Prelude> addIndex [('a', 1, 4), ('a', 2, 5), ('b', 1, 3), ('b', 0, 2), ('c', 1, 2)]
[('a',1,4,0),('a',2,5,0),('b',1,3,1),('b',0,2,1),('c',1,2,2)]
```

But note that we only look at the previous element, and hence for example if the `'a'` key occurs after `'c'`, we will increment the counter again:

```
Prelude> addIndex [('a', 1, 4), ('a', 2, 5), ('b', 1, 3), ('b', 0, 2), ('c', 1, 2), ('a', 3, 4)]
[('a',1,4,0),('a',2,5,0),('b',1,3,1),('b',0,2,1),('c',1,2,2),('a',3,4,3)]
```

This function will run in *linear* time *O(n)* whereas the functions you composed will run in *quadratic* time *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* since appending is done in linear time (as well as `last`, etc.).